# Which of the following are true based on this comparison?

Tags: materials

In the following chart, the horizontal line is **time** and vertical line is **temperature**. $K$ and $L$ are solid matters that are placed in two identical pots within the same room and are being heated up with identical heaters.

[image]

(Translation: Sıcaklık = temperature, Zaman = time, dak (dakika) = minute, maddesi = substance)

Which ones of the following are true?

A-) If $K$ and $L$ are different matters, they have the same mass.

B-) If masses of $K$ and $L$ are different, they can be the same matter.

C-) If masses of $K$ and $L$ are equal, they are different matters.

I chose "only $B$" which turned out to be wrong while the correct answer is "$B$ and $C$" and in the explanation it said "You picked the wrong answer because you think different matters can't have the same boiling/melting point." which is true because they **can't**, right?

Comment: In B) and C), I assume that one of the "matter"s should be "mass". Different matters can have the same boiling and melting points. It's not a unique characteristic and was used for identification in the past only because of its simple determination.

Comment: Your book refers to: substance A always has boiling point P, otherwise, it is not A. Substance B always has boiling point Q. P can equal Q, however.

Answer (score 1):

A is not true - no such connection exists.
B is true (and given the same temperature indicating the phase transition it is in fact likely that K and L are the same matter).
C is true and can be explained as follows: if K and L have the same mass, they must have different [specific heat capacities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity), defined as:

$$
c = \frac{\text{the amount of energy to be added to raise the temperature by 1°C}}{\text{mass}}
$$

This is a property that is unique for each matter - same as the melting and boiling point. It can be said to be a function of the matter. Note that the $T(t)$ graphs appear to start at the same temperature, but it takes longer to heat L than K to 85°C although the same heating is applied.

Comment: Maybe it is badly translated, I dunno. It *can* be water - true. If boiling point is *not* 100°C, it *cannot* be water - true.